# Rails Mysql: How to only include has_many relation object that meet my condition?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I have the following classes:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :keys
    end

    class Key < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :room
    end

    class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
      #has column "surface_area"
    end
```

I want to query all users that have keys with rooms with surface_area of 10, only including the keys with rooms that have a surface area of 10.

I have the following query:

```
User.joins(keys: :room).where('room.surface_area= ?', 10)
```

This returns the Users which have keys with room.surface_area of 10, but it includes all keys, so also keys that have room with a different surface area than 10. I only want to return the subset of the keys which have a room with the surface area of 10.

Wrong return value:

```
Users:{
 keys: [
  {id: 1, surface_area: 11},
  {id: 2, surface_area: 10},
  {id: 3, surface_area: 10}
 ]
}
```

Correct return value:

```
  Users:{
     keys: [
      {id: 2, surface_area: 10},
      {id: 3, surface_area: 10}
     ]
    }
```

json.rabl file for users

```
collection @users, :root => :users, :object_root => false

child :keys do
  extends "keys"
end
```

Comment: `User.joins(keys: :room).where(room: {surface_area: 10 })` try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.joins(keys: :room).where('room.surface_area= ?', 10)
```

This command queries users and returns users that have keys for rooms with surface area = 10. This is correct. But when you call `keys` on one of these users, you get all the keys they have. And this is also correct, because this is what `has_many :keys` association does.

What you need is to define a new instance method in User model, like so:

```
def keys_for_rooms_with_surface_area(area)
  keys.joins(:room).where('rooms.surface_area = ?', area)
end
```

If you want `has_many :keys` to always return keys for rooms with surface area = 10, you can do it like so:

```
has_many :keys, ->() { joins(:room).where('rooms.surface_area = 10') }
```

In this case your very first query would look like this:

```
User.joins(keys: :room)
```

Comment: Yes I just added a method 'keys_for_rooms_with_surface_area(area)' in User and called the function from the .rabl file and it works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not try...

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :keys do
      def surface_area surface_area
         joins(:room).where(room: { surface_area: surface_area })
      end
   end
end
```

This should give you the ability to call:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@user.keys.surface_area 10
```

I'll delete if it doesn't work, just a stab in the dark